# field in data file exceeds maximum length in sql loader. I am using in linux. we are getting the data from sybase and using it for oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am facing the field in data file exceeds maximum length in sql loader error while loading the data to oracle.

```
//Below control file is used for sqlldr
// Control File:   Product_Routing_26664.ctl
//Data File:      phxcase1.pr
//Bad File:     Product_Routing_26664.bad


LOAD DATA
APPEND INTO TABLE PEGASUSDB_SCHEMA.PRODUCT_ROUTING
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "^"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
        OID_INST                
        ,SEQ                    
        ,ROUTING_TYPE            CHAR "(CASE WHEN trim(:ROUTING_TYPE) IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE trim(:ROUTING_TYPE) END)"
        ,ODPD_KEY
        ,PROD_OFFSET
        ,EFF_DAYS_Z              CHAR "(CASE WHEN trim(:EFF_DAYS_Z) IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE trim(:EFF_DAYS_Z) END)"
        ,NETWORK_RTG_ID          "substr(trim(:NETWORK_RTG_ID), 3, 26)"
        ,WT0
        ,WT1
        ,WT2
        ,WT3
        ,WT4
        ,WT5
        ,WT6
        ,WT7
        ,WT8
        ,WT9
        ,WT10
        ,WT11
        ,WT12
        ,WT13
        ,WT14
        ,WT15
        ,WT16
        ,WT17
        ,WT18
        ,WT19
        ,WT20
        ,WT21
        ,WT22
        ,WT23
        ,WT24
        ,WT25
        ,WT26
        ,WT27
        ,WT28
        ,WT29
        ,WT30
        ,WT31
        ,WT32
        ,WT33
        ,WT34
        ,WT35
        ,PCS0
        ,PCS1
        ,PCS2
        ,PCS3
        ,PCS4
        ,PCS5
        ,PCS6
        ,PCS7
        ,PCS8
        ,PCS9
        ,PCS10
        ,PCS11
        ,PCS12
        ,PCS13
        ,PCS14
        ,PCS15
        ,PCS16
        ,PCS17
        ,PCS18
        ,PCS19
        ,PCS20
        ,PCS21
        ,PCS22
        ,PCS23
        ,PCS24
        ,PCS25
        ,PCS26
        ,PCS27
        ,PCS28
        ,PCS29
        ,PCS30
        ,PCS31
        ,PCS32
        ,PCS33
        ,PCS34
        ,PCS35
        ,PR_TYPE                 CHAR "(CASE WHEN trim(:PR_TYPE) IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE trim(:PR_TYPE) END)"
        ,PRODUCT_ROUTING_OID     "PRODUCT_ROUTING_SQ.nextval"
        ,COMMON_CASE_OID         CONSTANT "1"
        ,NETWORK_RTG_OID         "(select NETWORK_RTG_OID from NETWORK_RTG where NETWORK_RTG_ID = substr(TRIM(:NETWORK_RTG_ID), 3, 26) and COMMON_CASE_OID = 1)"
)
```

> Error:  Record 2: Rejected - Error on table
>   PEGASUSDB_SCHEMA.PRODUCT_ROUTING, column OID_INST. Field in data file
>   exceeds maximum length

I have tried changing the `OID_INST` column to `OID_INST  CHAR(4000)` but it shows the same error.

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Please post an extract of the file to load

Comment: @Aleksej : Do you want me to post the data file content?

Comment: As far as we know, the data file could even contain a single neverending string, thus causing the error. If possible, try to post the line of the datafile that gives error

Comment: @Aleksej : M ^▒"000010000001000000100000000000000000ʗ#X%0PM ^▒"000000000000000000000000010000000000ʗ#X%0
PM ^▒"010000001000000100000010000000000000ʗ#X%0

Comment: Please edit that into the question, and show the first few lines. What operating system are you running SQL\*Loader on, and where did the file come from? I'm wondering if you have a file with LF line endings, but are loading on Windows, which expects CRLF by default? But if so, odd that it's reported as record 2.

Comment: @AlexPoole : I am using in linux. Actually we are doing Dualwrite both in sybase and oracle. in oracle loading we are getting this problems

Comment: @Aleksej : datafile contains the binary data. can sqlloader load the binary data?